# Switch & Timer Nomenclature

Tags: switch, timer

GOAL: Connect a water heater and dryer to the same circuit, however, they shall be switch to ensure that only one is connected at any time.   A SPDT switch: 220V water heater at one pole and a Dryer at the other pole: **only one of the two devices will receive power at any time.**  I believe I am interested in a 220V 30A SPDT (Single Pole Double throw switch).

TIMER FUNCTIONALITY: water heater pole to be default (normally connected to 220V) and the user will switch the power from the water heater to the dryer.    The switch would be in a timer that after 2 hours it will revert (switch) back to the water heater.

QUESTION: What is the search term that I need to feed Google / Amazon so that it will return the unicorn that has been described?

Comment: Water heater  and dryer will both need 30 amps

Comment: Most water heaters and dryers usually are on 30 amp dedicated circuits and use both hots.  Basically what you want seems to be a big no-no.  Check your heater and dryer and add to your question if different from what we think.

Comment: Your question isn't really about home improvement. We don't do search terms for Google. We'd have to hunt like you should be doing.

Comment: @JACK  Thanks for the 30A insight

Comment: DPDT (switch both hots) & "contactor" for that power class. You de-unicorn it by using a relay (contactor) and then the timer/switch becomes easy to find, as it's just telling the relay to switch.

Comment: A two hour time delay relay.

Comment: I don't see a problem with switching one leg. What needs to be 2-pole is the disconnect and overcurrent protection (i.e. breaker). OP is basically looking for a 3-way switch that is 30A.